# How to control the seek bar, on click, of volume button during media playback in android?

Tags: android, volume, android-seekbar

How does one control the seek bar of the volume button in the media player in Android? I require to control the seek bar of the volume button's onClick method during playback.

The code has been provided here :

```
private void initControls() {
    // Return the handle to a system-level service - 'AUDIO'.
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    // Find the seekbar 1
    mediaVlmSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    // Set the max range(Volume in this case) of seekbar
    // for Media player volume
    mediaVlmSeekBar.setMax(audioManager
            .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
    // Set the progress with current Media Volume
    mediaVlmSeekBar.setProgress(audioManager
            .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

    try {
        // Listener to receive changes to the SeekBar1's progress level
        mediaVlmSeekBar
                .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                    }

                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                    }

                    // When progress level of seekbar1 is changed
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0,
                            int progress, boolean arg2) {
                        audioManager.setStreamVolume(
                                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//change seekbar when click device button
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) 
     { 
          mediaVlmSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
            int index = mediaVlmSeekBar.getProgress(); 
            mediaVlmSeekBar.setProgress(index + 1); 
            return true; 
     } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
      {
            int index = mediaVlmSeekBar.getProgress(); 
            mediaVlmSeekBar.setProgress(index - 1); 
            return true; 
     }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
     }
```

Comment: can't able to understand your question.please explain further

Comment: when media player is playback that time seek bar not update of volume when device up-down click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code and its working fine. Check out

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        seekBarVolume.setProgress(currentVolume);
        return false;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        seekBarVolume.setProgress(currentVolume);
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```